# How to position a counter badge without children in a List in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to create a ListItem within a List with a text and a badge counter on the right.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Badge,
  Card,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemButton,
  ListItemText,
} from "@material-ui/core";

const NavigationTree: React.FC = () => {
  const items = Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map((e) => (
    <ListItem
      key={e}
      dense
      disableGutters
      disablePadding
      divider
      secondaryAction={<Badge max={1e6} badgeContent={1234} color="primary" />}
    >
      <ListItemButton>
        <ListItemText
          primary="THIS IS AN ITEM"
        />
      </ListItemButton>
    </ListItem>
  ));

  return (
    <Card variant="outlined">
      <List dense disablePadding>
        {items}
      </List>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default NavigationTree;
```

However I get this weird badge which seems to be cut in half, and seems also not quite aligned with the text:

[image: demo]

How can I achieve a nice badge on the right with a slight margin from the right edge well aligned with the text?

Here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-monad-3ijih

Comment: can you post a sandbox? its a css thing but i couldnt manage to run this at codesandbox

Comment: sure, added to the OP

Comment: check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a small sandbox (you were using the latest version that's why my imports didnt work)

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-wood-jjuoe)

By adding this selector, you get the desired result

```
.MuiListItem-root .MuiBadge-badge {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

I added `MuiListItem-root` in order to limit the effect of it only inside this list.

In my sandbox i added a random generator to see how it renders with various digits (1,2,3 etc)